# Tensor Algebra: Universal Property

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, universal-property

Hi there in wiki the tensor algebra is defined w.r.t. the adjoint of the forgetful functor rather than the forgetful functor itself - why so?
Besides, does the existence of such algebras for every vector spaces correlate to the existence of the adjoint functor?

Moreover, can somebody carefully check wether I'm getting everything right in here: [image: Tensor Algebra]

Comment: What do you mean by "defined w.r.t. the adjoint of the forgetful functor"? The Wikipedia  page(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra) states that "[T is] left adjoint to the forgetful functor from algebras to vector spaces".

Comment: What I mean is that looking on the defining commuting diagram the adjoint functor appears rather than the forgetful functor itself - though it seems as if that diagram is kind of sloppy since it involves different categories same time ("Any linear transformation f : V → A from V to an algebra A [...]").

Comment: Are you talking about the diagram on the Wikipedia page? That is a bit sloppy, because it doesn't explicitly mention $U$. It really is looking at $i \colon V \to U(T(V))$ and $f \colon V \to U(A)$ and $\tilde f \colon T(V) \to A$ which gives $U(\tilde f) \colon U(T(V)) \to U(A)$. [I'll try to draw the diagram; give me a moment]. Or are you talking about the triangle you've drawn? Frankly, I can't make any sense of that.

Comment: Yes!!! So why do they then mention the adjoint functor at all?

Comment: Well, $T$ *is* left adjoint to $U$.

Comment: And yes, I'm talking about the diagram I've drawn. I mean that is a direct translation from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property

Comment: But that diagram is a very generic description of a universal arrow.  What you get (from the fact that $T$ and $U$ form an adjoint pair) is a universal arrow $V \to U(T(V))$. So, your $A$ - in that diagram - is really $T(V)$ and then it indeed states that every morphism $V \to U(C)$ of vector spaces gives rise to a (unique) morphism $A = T(V) \to C$ of algebras.

Comment: @Freeze_S Maybe you should review the definition of an adjoint pair in terms of unit and counits. The universal arrow $V\to UT(V)$ is the $V$ component of the unit. Since Wiki is giving the definition of the tensor algebra as a free construction (i.e., the right adjoint to the forgetful) you need to know, two right adjoints to a given functor are essentially the same.

Comment: @Freese_S You're diagram on the right doesn't capture the universal property in the definition. What you want is a diagram of vector spaces with $\eta_V\colon V\to UT(V)$ the universal element, meaning for every vector space morphism $f\colon V\to U(A)$ there is a unique arrow $\overline f\colon T(V)\to A$ such that $U\overline f\circ \eta_V=f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The universal property is defined via the forgetful functor: $\mathrm{U}:\mathrm{Alg}\to\mathrm{Vec}$
This defines its adjoint functor: $\mathrm{T}:\mathrm{Vec}\to\mathrm{Alg}$